# Explicit convert from object in ActionFilter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, implicit-conversion, action-filter

The goal is to create a ActionFilter to save all your contacts automatically.

### Code:

**ViewModels**

`Origem` is used to identify the view source of contact was saved (in this case only two views contato `ContatoViewModel` and Careers `TrabalheConoscoViewModel`)

```
public class ContatoViewModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Assunto { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Contato(ContatoViewModel vm)
    {
        return new Contato { Nome = vm.Nome, Email = vm.Email, PrimeiroContato = DateTime.Now, Origem = OrigemContato.Contato };
    }
}

public class TrabalheConoscoViewModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Contato(TrabalheConoscoViewModel vm)
    {
        return new Contato{ Nome = vm.Nome, Email = vm.Email, PrimeiroContato=DateTime.Now, Origem = OrigemContato.Candidato };
    }
}
```

**Filter**

```
public class LogContatoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _paramName;
    private object _paramValue = null;
    public LogContatoAttribute(string paramName = "vm")
    {
        _paramName = paramName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(_paramName))
            _paramValue = filterContext.ActionParameters[_paramName];
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Parâmetro não encontrado.", _paramName);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var a = (Contato)_paramValue; //Error!!!!

        // Save in database

    }
}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult contato()
{
    return View(new ContatoViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[LogContato("vm")]
public ActionResult contato(ContatoViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        new mailController().contato(vm).Deliver();
        return RedirectToRoute("Default", new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "home" }, { "action", "contato" } });
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Não foi possível enviar sua mensagem.");
    return View(vm);
}
```

### Error

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'CreditoImobiliarioBB.WebSite.ViewModels.ContatoViewModel' to type 'CreditoImobiliarioBB.WebSite.Models.Contato'.
  Source=CreditoImobiliarioBB.WebSite
  StackTrace:
       at CreditoImobiliarioBB.WebSite.Infra.Filters.LogContatoAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) in w:\Clients\creditoimobiliariobb\website\src\CreditoImobiliarioBB.WebSite\Infra\Filters\LogContato.cs:line 27
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException:
```

[image: Error]

### Question

I believe it is because the `_paramValue` is a object.
How implicit convert from an object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is certainly caused because the type you're calling the conversion on is `object`.

You also can't create implicit conversions from the base `object` type. You'll need to cast to the correct type before you're able to use your implicit converter.

I'm not a big fan of using implicit/explicit conversion operators. I much prefer a propper mapping solution like AutoMapper.

Comment: I use AutoMapper but this problem is very punctual. I do not think that justifies AutoMapper (at least for now).

Any other way to solve this problem without AutoMapper?

Comment: If you want to continue using your conversion operator then you just need to cast to the right type. You could impliment this as a simple `if (_paramValue is ContatoViewModel){ // cast it here and convert }`.